# R - geom_smooth, add se for only one line

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing, confidence-interval

Is there a way, in `geom_smooth()` (from libray **ggplot2**), to have the confidence interval (parameters `se = T`) for a line but not for the other ?

```
mpg %>% 
   filter(class %in% c('compact', 'midsize')) %>% 
   ggplot(aes(x = displ, y = as.numeric(hwy), color = class)) + 
      geom_smooth(se = T)
```

In the graph below, I would like to keep the confidence interval for the blue line, but to remove the one of the red line. As `se` parameter is not in the `aes()` function, I don't manage to pass different values in it.
Moreover, there is no function like `scale_fill_manual()`, to specify different values.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
mpg %>% 
  filter(class %in% c('compact', 'midsize')) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = displ, y = as.numeric(hwy), color = class)) + 
  geom_smooth(data = . %>% filter(class == "compact"), method = "loess", se = F) +
  geom_smooth(data = . %>% filter(class == "midsize"), method = "loess", se = T)
```